# How to add more than one editview to submit to email intent

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, android-edittext

I am trying to have more than one Edittext fields to send via a intent to email.

the code will make more sense of what i am trying to accomplish,

```
public class EmailSupport extends Activity {

  Button buttonSend;
  String textTo;
  EditText textSubject;
  EditText nametext;
  EditText emailtext;
  EditText phonetext;
  EditText topictext;
  EditText detailstext;


@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.email_form_to_support);

        public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] recipients = new String[]{"email@email.com", "email@email.com",};
          String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
          String name = nametext.getText().toString();
          String emails = emailtext.getText().toString();
          String phone = phonetext.getText().toString();
          String topic = topictext.getText().toString();
          String details = detailstext.getText().toString();


          Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emails);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, phone);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, topic);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, details);
```

I need to know how to incorporate all the edittext inputs as see in the layout file below to basic add to the message text in the email. my topic edittext is my subject for the email and i want to hardline a email address to send it too by default.

email_form_to_support.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nametext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/phone" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phonetext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/topic" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/topictext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/details" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/detailstext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciate. I feel like im just missing something simple however i may be wrong. So far with this method of source i am getting errors on the String message = xxxtext.getText().toString(); because i have it several time. I dont know what to put for each one.

Per Pavel Dudka recommended I change my Source to This

```
 public class EmailSupport extends Activity {

Button buttonSend;
String textTo;
EditText textSubject;
EditText nametext;
EditText emailtext;
EditText phonetext;
EditText topictext;
EditText detailstext;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_form_to_support);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    textTo = (String) getString(R.string.to);
    textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.topictext);
    nametext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
    phonetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonetext);
    topictext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.topictext);
    detailstext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detailstext);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuilder emailBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            emailBodyBuilder.append(textSubject.getText().toString());
            emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
            emailBodyBuilder.append(nametext.getText().toString());
            emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
            emailBodyBuilder.append(emailtext.getText().toString());
            emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
            emailBodyBuilder.append(topictext.getText().toString());
            emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
            emailBodyBuilder.append(phonetext.getText().toString());
            emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
            emailBodyBuilder.append(detailstext.getText().toString());

            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new  String[]{"email1@domen.com", "email2@domen.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, textSubject.getText().toString());
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBodyBuilder.toString());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Did you initialize your `EditText`s before you use `getText().toString()`?

Comment: as In This `Button buttonSend;
 String textTo;
 EditText textSubject;
 EditText nametext;
 EditText emailtext;
 EditText phonetext;
 EditText topictext;
 EditText detailstext;`

Comment: No. As in `TextView nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametext);`and the rest of your views also.

Comment: No i did not here in my java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what you are trying to accomplish but change this:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    String[] recipients = new String[]{"email@email.com", "",};
      String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
      String message = nametext.getText().toString();
      String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
      String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
      String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
```

to this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String[] recipients = new String[]{"email@email.com", "email2@email.com"};
    String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
    String name = nametext.getText().toString();
    String email = emailtext.getText().toString();
    String phone = phonetext.getText().toString();
    String topics = topicstext.getText().toString();
    String details = deatilstext.getText().toString();

    // Do something with this Strings
}
```

Here each EditText is stored in it's own String, for you to use as you please.

**Addition from comments**

Simply combine the Strings, this is one easy way:

```
String message = nametext.getText().toString();
message += "\n" + emailtext.getText().toString();
etc.
```

Where a "\n" is a line break like using <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can setup a more interesting format between the fields, perhaps:

```
message += "\n\nEmail:\n" + emailtext.getText().toString();
```

But that is up to you.

Comment: im jsut trying to send a email with the body of the message to include the text from the name, email, phone, topic, details edittext. so the output would be a prefinded email address, the subject would be a string, and then the message would include multiple strings, not just one, but all of the name, email, etc strings

Comment: I updated my source with what you recommended and added what i thought might work. see the `email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, xxx);` stuff

Comment: I am working on what you recommended as well and will respond back with results

Comment: This works great, the only thing can i apply a \nsomething:\n to the first section to look like this `String message = "\nName:\n" nametext.getText().toString();`

Comment: Of course, put you need to add the `+` operator between the Strings: `String message = "\nName:\n" + nametext.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StringBuilder to compose an email body. Consider using following code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    StringBuilder emailBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    emailBodyBuilder.append(textSubject.getText().toString());
    emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
    emailBodyBuilder.append(nametext.getText().toString());
    emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
    emailBodyBuilder.append(emailtext.getText().toString());
    emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
    emailBodyBuilder.append(topicstext.getText().toString());
    emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
    emailBodyBuilder.append(phonetext.getText().toString());
    emailBodyBuilder.append("\n");
    emailBodyBuilder.append(deatilstext.getText().toString());

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email1@domen.com", "email2@domen.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, textSubject.getText().toString());
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBodyBuilder.toString());
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
}
```

`activity` - is Activity reference you need to store to be able to send intents. In case you perform `onClick` handling within your `Activity`, you can omit this, so last line in my code sample would look like:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

If you start getting NullPointer exceptions while accessing your edit text views, make sure you got initialized them. Something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_form_to_support);
    textSubject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    ...//and so forth
```

Comment: I guess i am not understanding what you mean by activity you need to store, would this refer to my main acitivity or this activity. . This activity does have a onclick, when the layout button is clicked `buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` the email needs to be created and sent to the android system and the user clicks the client they want.

Comment: I have updated my source above with what you recommended and the android emulator now says there is not a application to do the intent

Comment: it would refer to this activity. So if you are using inner class to create a click handler (`buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` - you can get reference to your activity by using this: `YourActivityName.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")` In this way you will send e-mail activity and Android will propose you to choose appropriate e-mail client

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment android emulator does not have e-mail client installed. That's why it complains about lack of client. On real device it will work

Comment: Or as an alternative, you can set up a gmail account in emulator. This will automatically enable native e-mail client. You can do this by going to Settings->Account->Add account

Comment: Thank you both answer in the post work great, thank you @Pavel Dudka